# What specs should I use for my .NET webapp on Azure, or something similar?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, cloud

So I'm pretty green to the industry, please excuse what I'm assuming is huge swaths of ignorance. I'm looking to develop an ASP.NET webapp (with a SQL Server db) as a kind of in-house tool for our employees, accessible from anywhere. We're a company with virtually no IT infrastructure, so these employees (~100) will be accessing this application from all around the country on what are basically personal computers. I don't ever expect there to be any more than 10 users using the webapp concurrently. The web app is going to be the frame for a series of tools I've been making for the head office guys, but from a central point that's easy for me to maintain.

We have our own domain, so that's taken care of.

I'd like to find a cloud-based tool that would pretty much just involve me deploying my code to it, and that's about it. I've take a look at Azure and that seems like the way to go, but I know if I present a price too high the bosses won't exactly be thrilled.

I was hoping some of you guys had some experience in setting these kinds of things up. Here's a series of questions I'm having a hard time coming up with an answer for:

1. Looking at the Azure cloud-based webapp, What da heck specs do I get? Is Standard S2 too much power, or nowhere near enough?
2. Do I need to purchase an Azure SQL Server thingo seperate to the Web App hosting, or does it come bundled in?
3. How the heck do I deploy my dang code?

I've been getting off pretty easily as I used to have a team behind me, and now I'm alone at a new company, there's not many people whose brains I can pick. I've had a call or two with a Microsoft employee, and they were helpful, but not entirely helpful enough. They keep assuming I know what I'm doing - I don't. So any help from anyone would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry Kyle, but that question is too broad for SO.

Comment: Welcome to SO Kyle! For 1) Check the pricing page. You will get the hardware specifications there and based on that you can determine if S2 is powerful enough for you. For 2) the answer is yes, you will need to purchase SQL Server separately. Look into Azure SQL Database. For 3) Just do a search and you will find ways to deploy your code in Azure WebApps.

Comment: Regarding question one, Azure web app has different price tiers, the different tiers have different features and performance. For more details, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn two services of Azure:

**1.[Azure Web app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview):**

Azure App Service is an HTTP-based service for hosting web applications, REST APIs, and mobile back ends. You can develop in your favorite language, be it .NET, .NET Core, Java, Ruby, Node.js, PHP, or Python. Applications run and scale with ease on both Windows and Linux-based environments.

This document will teach you develop web app with Azure SQL and deploy your app to Azure.

**2. [Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview):**

Azure SQL Database is a general-purpose relational database, provided as a managed service. With it, you can create a highly available and high-performance data storage layer for the applications and solutions in Azure. SQL Database can be the right choice for a variety of modern cloud applications because it enables you to process both relational data and non-relational structures, such as graphs, JSON, spatial, and XML.

Azure SQL database is a cloud database. If you have the develop experience with SQL server, you will be familiar to it.

Azure App Service and Azure SQL database are independent, in Azure, which service you want to use, just pay for it.

You need an Azure Web app service to host your app,  and you also need a Azure SQL database. Then you can develop the app with Azure SQL database.

Each service has the different price tier to meet the performance requirements of the user. You need to choose the most suitable for your company to save the money.

Hope this helps.